# MVC3 C# LocalizedRequiredAttribute not works

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

I wrote this attribute extension:

```
public class LocalizedRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public LocalizedRequiredAttribute(string resourceTag)
    {
        ErrorMessage = GetMessageFromResource(resourceTag);
    }

    private static String GetMessageFromResource(String resourceTag)
    {
        return ResourceManager.Current.GetResourceString(resourceTag);
    }
}
```

but I get this error: 'System.Resources.ResourceManager' does not contain a definition for 'Current'.

What is wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can already be done using the [RequiredAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx)

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(ClassLib1.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName="Character_FirstName_Required")]
```

see [Model Metadata and Validation Localization using Conventions](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/07/14/model-metadata-and-validation-localization-using-conventions.aspx)

---

EDIT:
I Guess you're referencing the wrong ResourceManager, see [ResourceManager.Current | current property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206082%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to Localize (extend) the base attribute cause I want to pass only the ResourceLabel, and get the ResourceType automatically. Thanks again.

Comment: I resolved in part. Now the LocalizedAttribute validates only server side, and not client side... but if I use the base Attribute work fine in my client. Any idea? Thanks. Luca

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core namespace referenced in the file where you define this attribute so VS in it's wisdom is referencing System.Resources.Resource manager.

Comment: Hi Kell, I resolved in part. Now the LocalizedAttribute validates only server side, and not client side... but if I use the base Attribute work fine in my client. Any idea? Thanks. Luca

Comment: You will have to add java script to get the client side validation working. It's been a few years since I did this sort of thing with asp.net. Hopefully this will give you some ideas: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/customvalidationscripts.aspx